# Fixed positon menu covers section content

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I made menu like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#p1">Paragraph 1</a>
  <a href="#p2">Paragraph 2</a>
  ...
</div>
```

and I made it position fixed:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

There's also a content div:

```
<div id="content">
  <p id="p1">...
  <p id="p2">...
  ...
</div>
```

With its style:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
```

It works perfect when I just scroll over my page, but when I use these section links from my menu eg. href="#p8", the menu covers a part of this paragraph.

What should I do with it?

## edit

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hcvuw4s9/

*try paragraph 3

Comment: Can u please make a jsfiddle link of your code?

Comment: here you are http://jsfiddle.net/hcvuw4s9/ (try paragraph 3)

Answer (score 2):

```
#content p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/ws34m9m7/

Comment: I just got what you asked. Fixed my main answer :)

Comment: It's a kind of solution but I don't want a menu-height gap between each paragraphs. Is there another way to do this? It is a course exercise so it should be possible to do that :D

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution except this one. When you use fixed position, it automatically get rids from HTML itself and all other elements shift up. I can't explain it well (english isn't my natural language).

Comment: Mine neither :) I hope someone else will try to help me too

Comment: Nope. "Pure css". I not allowed even touch HTML.

Comment: If you somehow allowed modify html, this is solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/ws34m9m7/1/. I really don't think you can achieve it either without touch html or my first solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It could be it is just impossible because my teacher is a kind of sadist.